Can you call WCF SOAP based endpoints using Azure API/M?
How can I call my WCF Soap based messages using Azure API/M?  We have http offloading as well.  What do I need to do in order to allow those messages thru API/M?

Yes, you can add a new api in APIM and import your SOAP service by using a wsdl. Make sure to set the url scheme to HTTP(s).

i will try!  thank you!

i think that's it... will apply it as answer. if it doesnt work i will revoke.
